# DateTime value of an API's response in C# web API shows different behavior based on .NET version

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple C# Web API.

```
[HttpGet]
public DateTime GetDateResponse()
{
    var a = DateTime.Parse("2023-09-26 12:28:20.793");
    return a;
}
```

When I run this in *.NET framework 4.7.2 I* am getting the following result:

```
2023-09-26T12:28:20.793Z
```

However, when I run this in *.NET 6 Web API*, the result becomes:

```
2023-09-26T12:28:20.793
```

.NET Framework interprets result as UTC, however the .NET 6 doesn't have the timezone info, even though the `Kind` property of both these `DateTime` objects is "Unspecified"

I believe the behavior in .NET 6 is right since there is no timezone information and it shouldn't interpret it as UTC.

But, I was migrating my application from .NET framework to .NET 6 and this change in behavior is causing all my date values to be shown as wrong in the client side. Is there any way to have a control over this? Like configure using a middleware or something to have the same behavior as before?

Please note that, when we return a `DateTime.Now`, then behavior is same on both versions

```
[HttpGet]
public DateTime GetDateResponse()
{
    var a = DateTime.Now;
    return a;
}
```

Well, not exactly same, in the .NET framework, it converts the current date to UTC and gives the result with the `Z` at the end. In .NET 6, it appends the timezone as well in the result as follows. But this is fine since, both these results refer to the same time.

Comment: The results you're giving us are from converting those `DateTime` values to strings. You need to look at the actual `DateTime` values and see what the differences are, if any. For all we know, the difference is actually in how you're using the data.

Comment: Are `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` properties same for both projects?

Comment: My psychic debugging powers tell me that this is a case of Newtonsoft.Json vs System.Text.Json. But, nowhere near enough information here, and particularly nowhere near enough debugging attempted.

Comment: @Orifjon Yes, they're the same